# How can I serve a Bokeh document loaded from a JSON?

Tags: bokeh

I want to serialize a bokeh document to JSON, load it again using `from_json` and `from_json_string` [3] and serve it.

However, most examples out there either create their server by modifying `curdoc` [1] or by creating an application that receives and modifies a document [2].

The fact that I am using holoviews to generate the plot should not change the question, so this is not in anyway a holoviews question ;).

```py
import pandas as pd
import holoviews as hv
from bokeh.document import Document
from bokeh.io.doc import curdoc, set_curdoc
import json
hv.extension('matplotlib')
hv.extension('bokeh')

print("- create dummy data")
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=[1, 2], y=[0, 1]))
print(df)

print("- plot as holoviews curve")
curve = hv.Curve(df, 'x', 'y', label='curve1').opts(ylabel='y')

print("- render in bokeh")
plot = hv.render(curve, backend='bokeh')

print("- serialize as bokeh document to JSON")
doc = Document()
doc.add_root(plot)
doc_json = doc.to_json()
json_string = json.dumps(doc_json)

print("- deserialize as bokeh document")
doc2 = Document.from_json_string(json_string)
print(doc2.roots[0])
```

Now I do want to create something like the following:

```py
print("- embed document in bokeh application")
from bokeh.application.application import Application
app = Application()
app.initialize_document(doc)

print("- start bokeh server")
from bokeh.server.server import Server
server = Server(
    {'/fubar':app},  # list of Bokeh applications
    port=5010,
    num_procs=1
)

print("- starting server on 'http://localhost:5010/fubar'")
server.start()
server.io_loop.start()
```

This does actually run, but does not show anything in my browser. The reason is, that the Application actually requires a `Handler` and not a `Document`. But I found no documentation on how I can translate the one to the other.

Tl;Dr How can I configure the bokeh server to serve a deserialized document?

[1] https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html
[2] https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/application/handlers/function.html
[3] https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/document.html

Comment: Could you have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55628401/unable-to-embed-json-bokeh-plot-in-django-template/55631509#55631509) if it can help you?

Comment: Hi Tony, sorry I missed your comment before. Your method has the disadvantage, that it only supports the static content of the plot. I also need the dynamic content, which in turn requires a Bokeh server.

Comment: After not getting any answers here, I also asked the question in bokeh's google group: https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!msg/bokeh/U-nt8nUqlvY/sCMO-XOQCgAJ

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Bryan Van de Ven](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!msg/bokeh/U-nt8nUqlvY/sCMO-XOQCgAJ), I finally got it. The trick is to use `replace_with_json` instead!

```py
import pandas as pd
import holoviews as hv
from bokeh.document import Document
from bokeh.io.doc import curdoc, set_curdoc
import json
hv.extension('matplotlib')
hv.extension('bokeh')

print("- create dummy data")
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=[1, 2], y=[0, 1]))
print(df)

print("- plot as holoviews curve")
curve = hv.Curve(df, 'x', 'y', label='curve1').opts(ylabel='y')

print("- render in bokeh")
plot = hv.render(curve, backend='bokeh')

print("- serialize as bokeh document to JSON")
doc = Document()
doc.add_root(plot)
doc_json = doc.to_json()
json_string = json.dumps(doc_json)

print("- deserialize as bokeh document")
curdoc().replace_with_json(json.loads(json_string))
```

Unfortunately this does not work nicely with dynamic content created with holoviews. In a more complicated example, only the static content was preserved. It seems that for these cases, there is currently really no other method than really executing the analysis on the server.